# Write to two Kafka topics in a single transaction using Spring Kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to work out if there's a way of using Kafka's transaction feature to write to two topics within a transaction.

I know the typical scenario to use Kafka's transactions is in a consumer-producer pattern and that seems well documented.

What I've tried:

1. created a `KafkaTransactionManager` per topic
2. configured each `ProducerFactory` to use their respective transaction manager
3. Created a `ChainedTransactionManger` with the two instances of `KafkaTransactionManager`
4. Created a `KafkaTemplate` per topic

   I then used the `@Transactional(transactionManager = "chainedTx")` annotation on a method that that does:

   ```
   template1.send("topic1", "example payload");
   template2.send("topic2", "example payload");
   ```

This doesn't work. The `KafkaTemplate` is transactional, but when the `send()` method is called, there is no transaction in progress and I get an `IllegalStateException`.

I was going to try the `KafkaTemplate.executeInTransaction()` method, but the Javadoc states this is only for local transactions, so it does not appear to fit my needs.

My next step is to try using Kafka's Producer API directly to see if this pattern works, but I'd appreciate it if someone can tell me know that I'm wasting my time and Kafka doesn't support transactionally writing to multiple topics.

I did find this statement in Confluent's blog on Kafka transaction support:

> Transactions enable atomic writes to multiple Kafka topics and partitions...

But I haven't found any examples that demonstrate it.

**Configuration of the first producer**

@Configuration
    public class ControlProducerConfig {

```
@Bean("controlTransactionManager")
KafkaTransactionManager<String, String> transactionManager() {
    return  new KafkaTransactionManager<>(factory());
}

@Bean("controlTemplate")
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> template() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(factory());
}

private ProducerFactory<String, String> factory() {
    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String> factory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config());
    factory.setTransactionIdPrefix("abcd");
    return factory;
}

private Map<String, Object> config() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");

    props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/");

    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);

    // you can't set idempotence without setting max in flight requests to <= 5
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, 1);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, "1234");

    return props;
}
```

}

**Configuration of the second producer**

```
@Configuration
public class PayloadProducerConfig {


@Bean("payloadTransactionManager")
KafkaTransactionManager<String, String> transactionManager() {
    return new KafkaTransactionManager<>(factory());
}

@Bean("payloadTemplate")
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> template() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(factory());
}

private ProducerFactory<String, String> factory() {
    DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, String> factory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config());
    factory.setTransactionIdPrefix("abcd");
    return factory;
}

private Map<String, Object> config() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");

    props.put("schema.registry.url", "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/");

    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);

    // you can't set idempotence without setting max in flight requests to <= 5
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, 1);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.TRANSACTIONAL_ID_CONFIG, "1234");

    return props;
}
```

}

**Main class**

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}

@Bean("chainedTx")
public ChainedTransactionManager chained(
    @Qualifier("controlTransactionManager") KafkaTransactionManager controlTransactionManager,
    @Qualifier("payloadTransactionManager") KafkaTransactionManager payloadTransactionManager) {

    return new ChainedTransactionManager(controlTransactionManager, payloadTransactionManager);
}

@Bean OnStart onStart(PostTwoMessages postTwoMessages) {
    return new OnStart(postTwoMessages);
}

@Bean
public PostTwoMessages postTwoMessages(
    @Qualifier("controlTemplate") KafkaTemplate<String, String> controlTemplate,
    @Qualifier("controlTemplate") KafkaTemplate<String, String> payloadTemplate) {

    return new PostTwoMessages(controlTemplate, payloadTemplate);
}
```

}

**On application start**

```
public class OnStart implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

private PostTwoMessages postTwoMessages;

public OnStart(PostTwoMessages postTwoMessages) {
    this.postTwoMessages = postTwoMessages;
}

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
    postTwoMessages.run();
}
```

}

**Posting the two messages**

```
public class PostTwoMessages  {

private final KafkaTemplate<String, String> controlTemplate;
private final KafkaTemplate<String, String> payloadTemplate;

public PostTwoMessages(
    @Qualifier("controlTemplate") KafkaTemplate<String, String> controlTemplate,
    @Qualifier("payloadTemplate") KafkaTemplate<String, String> payloadTemplate) {

    this.controlTemplate = controlTemplate;
    this.payloadTemplate = payloadTemplate;
}

@Transactional(transactionManager = "chainedTx")
public void run() {
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    controlTemplate.send("private.s0869y.trx.model3a", "control: " + uuid);
    payloadTemplate.send("private.s0869y.trx.model3b", "payload: " + uuid);
}
```

}

Comment: Garry Russell's accepted answer helped clear up a misconception about needing different producers when sending different format messages to different topics. This is not the case.

Comment: If you are using Avro serialization, then the composite serializer is not required. Configure Avro serialization as normal and use Object as the KafkaTemplate value type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should work; do you have `@EnableTransactionManagement`?

However, transactions can't span 2 different producers; you have to do both sends using the same template. Otherwise it's 2 different transactions.

**EDIT**

Here's an example with a Spring Boot application:

**EDIT2**

Update example to show using a local transaction via `executeInTransaction`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So54865968Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So54865968Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(Foo foo) {
        return args -> {
            foo.runInTx();
            System.out.println("Committed 1");
            foo.runInLocalTx();
            System.out.println("Committed 2");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Foo foo(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> template) {
        return new Foo(template);
    }

    @Bean
    public Bar bar() {
        return new Bar();
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic1() {
        return new NewTopic("so54865968-1", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic2() {
        return new NewTopic("so54865968-2", 1, (short) 1);
    }

    public static class Foo {

        private final KafkaTemplate<String, Object> template;

        public Foo(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> template) {
            this.template = template;
        }

        @Transactional(transactionManager = "kafkaTransactionManager")
        public void runInTx() throws InterruptedException {
            this.template.send("so54865968-1", 42);
            this.template.send("so54865968-2", "texttest");
            System.out.println("Sent 2; waiting a few seconds to commit");
            Thread.sleep(5_000);
        }

        public void runInLocalTx() throws InterruptedException {
            this.template.executeInTransaction(t -> {
                t.send("so54865968-1", 43);
                t.send("so54865968-2", "texttest2");
                System.out.println("Sent 2; waiting a few seconds to commit");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5_000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                return true;
            });
        }

    }

    public static class Bar {

        @KafkaListener(id = "foo", topics = { "so54865968-1", "so54865968-2" })
        public void haandler(byte[] bytes) {
            if (bytes.length == 4) {
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
                System.out.println("Received int " + bb.getInt());
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Received string " + new String(bytes));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix=tx-id
spring.kafka.producer.properties.value.serializer=com.example.CompositeSerializer

spring.kafka.consumer.enable-auto-commit=false
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.isolation.level=read_committed
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
```

and

```
public class CompositeSerializer implements Serializer<Object> {

    private final StringSerializer stringSerializer = new StringSerializer();

    private final IntegerSerializer intSerializer = new IntegerSerializer();

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, Object data) {
        return data instanceof Integer ? intSerializer.serialize(topic, (Integer) data)
                : stringSerializer.serialize(topic, (String) data);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

}
```

and

```
Received int 42
Received string texttest
```

Both showed up after the 5 second pause.

Comment: The messages are two different formats, so it would be two different producers. Should it be possible to chain the two transactions? @EnableTransactionManagement is on the main class.

Comment: Yes; chaining the transactions should work, as long as you understand they are not atomic updates. If you have transactions enabled then it should work ok, as long as you call the `@Transactional` method from another bean (internal method calls won't start a transaction). If you still can't figure it out, post more of your code/config. I would, however look into making a smart serializer that is able to handle both types.

Comment: Is there some write-up you can point me to on the topic of smart serializers? We have a pattern of separating the publishing of the event and the data payload of the event due to potential size of the payload, so I'm unclear on your suggestion.

Comment: I do understand that it won't be a single atomic transaction if/when I get it working ;-)

Comment: How are you currently serializing? - if using JSON it will just work. If you have some kind of custom serializer (or Avro etc). Write a simple serializer that delegates to the right serializer based on the record value type.

Comment: We are using Avro. Some consumers will want the event, some will want the event and payload, so I don't see that we could combine the messages onto a single topic, but as I'm new to Kafka (but not messaging middleware), I may be missing something.

Comment: It doesn't have to be in one topic; you can write to multiple topics with the same KafkaTemplate (as long as the serializer can handle both types).

Comment: You are calling `run()` from within the same class - why bypasses Spring's proxy and the transaction interceptor. You have to call an `@Transactional` method from another `@Bean`.

Comment: The writing to multiple topics with the single producer would be under a single transaction? I knew the root of this particular problem would be something on the stupid/simple end of the scale!

Comment: Tweaked the code to call the run() method from an injected dependency, but still get the same error. Checking with the debugger, I can see the PostTwoMessages object is a CGLIB proxy.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I added an example that works - it uses Boot's autoconfigured infrastructure but that just simplifies the config. It will work with and without Spring Boot.

Comment: I updated the example to show how to use a local transaction using `executeInTransaction()` instead of `@Transactional`.